# Possible to query a cached collection of entries in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, arel

I am caching the results of a model like so (with Memcached):

```
Rails.cache.fetch('Store.all') { Store.all }
```

Later, I am wanting to retrieve a subset of Store.all, such as stores in a certain city. Is there an easy way to query the already cached set of Stores, or do I need to hit the database again for each query?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember, the database is optimized for doing queries matching arbitrary conditions, and the cache store is just a fast lookup given you have a known key. You should use cache only for things that you've already filtered or prepared.

Assuming a cache key like `cities/1/stores` for all the stores in city 1, you could cache this collection and fetch it again later.

If you have a large number of stores, It would be an anti-optimization to try and cache `Store.all` as one cache key and then try to filter it with ruby for a given city or any other criteria. Your program would be forced to iterate over *all* the cities, since arrays don't have indexes on `city_id`. You'd be much better off letting the database do this work with a "where" clause and use the indexing power the database provides.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with ruby. First, fetch your results from cache, then iterate through the collection to find stores in a given city. Assuming you are using memcached, there is no easy way to query it, since it's a simple key:value store.